# Symfony / Doctrine - Listener - Encrypt / Decrypt

Tags: symfony

I have listener for encryption and decryption.
Encrypt:

```
public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $entity = $args->getEntity();


    if ($entity instanceof Customer) {
        $entity->setEmail($this->encryption->encrypt($entity->getEmail()));
        $entity->setPhone($this->encryption->encrypt($entity->getPhone()));
    } elseif ($entity instanceof Address) {
        $entity->setFirstName($this->encryption->encrypt($entity->getFirstName()));
        $entity->setLastName($this->encryption->encrypt($entity->getLastName()));
        $entity->setCompanyName($this->encryption->encrypt($entity->getCompanyName()));
        $entity->setStreet($this->encryption->encrypt($entity->getStreet()));
        $entity->setCity($this->encryption->encrypt($entity->getCity()));
    }

    return;
}

public function postLoad(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $entity = $args->getEntity();


    if ($entity instanceof Customer) {
        $entity->setEmail($this->encryption->decrypt($entity->getEmail()));
        $entity->setPhone($this->encryption->decrypt($entity->getPhone()));
    } elseif ($entity instanceof Address) {
        $entity->setFirstName($this->encryption->decrypt($entity->getFirstName()));
        $entity->setLastName($this->encryption->decrypt($entity->getLastName()));
        $entity->setCompanyName($this->encryption->decrypt($entity->getCompanyName()));
        $entity->setStreet($this->encryption->decrypt($entity->getStreet()));
        $entity->setCity($this->encryption->decrypt($entity->getCity()));
    }

    return;
}
```

Problem is with decryption part.
How to modify data on load without saving it in database? Right now it's updating encrypted data with decrypted onload.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you encryp/decrypt in your getters/setters?

Comment: @LioraHaydont I was told that Listener is better solution... Mb I can do decryption in getters.

Comment: What is not working in your current code?

Comment: How it should work:
prePersist: encrypt data and save to db.
postLoad: temporarily(without persisting/saving to DB) decrypt data from DB when I'm accessing it in twig or controller.
------
How it's working:
prePersist: As expected.
postLoad: It's updating existing(encrypted) data in DB to decrypted ones.

Comment: which library are you using to encrypt/decrypt values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that you shouldn't use a `prePersist` event as this event is only called when you add an entity to that database, but not when you update one.

In the list of Doctrine lifecycle events [here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events), you can see that the event you'd want to use is `preUpdate` so that on every change, it is encrypted again before being saved

Comment: Thanks for help. I really appreciate it .